# Зависает JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring-boot

Всем привет, на Spring Boot настроен оправка email. 
В yam настроено

```
spring:
  mail:
   host: <host>
   username: <user>
    password: <pass>
    port: 25
```

Далее согласно примеру из сети идет настройки хелпера и тд и отправка

```
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
log.info("Method sendHtmlMail");
...
mailSender.send(message);
log.info("message with sendTo");
```

Сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, что вроде все нормально работает отправляет потом в один момент перестает работать, запись в логе вижу, что пришел объект прошел по хелперу и далее в send, но после лога нет, то есть он своего рода завис, как отловить что там не так не понимаю, уже что только не делал. Почтовики тоже говорят, что сообщение не видят.

При этом, например, точно такое же сообщение, на такой же адрес отправлялось. Зависание пропадает после перезаупска приложения, потом сможет сутки поработать и опять зависнуть.

Помогите понять, что не так, и можно какой-то эксепшен словить? Может какие -то еще свойства нужны, может не так идет обработка сообщения?

Comment: Коннект связи стабильный? JVM хватает ресурсов? - это что первое в голову приходит.

Comment: Да вроде, я например инициализирую тестувую отправку с другой среды, и все ок. Соединение есть, логин пароль верный. Меня смущает что даже нет эксепшенов, просто замирает и все.