# Проблема с CompletableFuture

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, concurrency

Всем привет, у меня приложение отправляет письмо на почту, иногда почтовый сервер зависает и ничего не отдает, и соответственно приложение на отправку тоже, лечится после рестарта приложения. Чтобы этого избежать,я  решил воспользоваться таймаутом CompletableFuture, и отпускать метод, чтобы продолжать отправку. С многопоточностью не работал совсем, поэтому посмотрел в интернете.

Вот мой код

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mailSender.send(message);
        log.info("End post!");
    }
});

try {
    future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    log.info("GET TIMEOUT FROM POST SERVICE!");
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Все работало хорошо неделю, в логах видно что использовался `ForkJoinPool

INFO  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5]: End post!`

Но сегодня, почему-то приложения начало постоянно отваливаться на таймауте. Не понимал что не так, начал писать даже сетевикам.

Потом решил убрать свою фичу, и вооля работает, опять включил, снова по таймауту отваливается.

После решил добавить `Executor`
`ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`
и передавать его в runAsync.

Все заработало. сейчас тянет из пула `[pool-507-thread-1]: End post!`

В логе кстати число увеличивается постоянно с каждым сообщением 508, 509 и т.д.

Вопрос, что могло почти не так? Может я что-то сделал криво, помогите плиз. Вопрос просто суперсрочный(((

Вот первая часть вопроса, тут описан как раз класс выше
[Зависает JavaMailSender](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1106894/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-javamailsender)

Comment: В переменной mailSender находится потокобезопасный объект?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это экземпляр Спрингового класса JavaMailSender

Comment: Жаль,что никто не смог помочь.